# Accessing Testnet

Tags: blockchain, testnet, op-return

Can i access the testnet without downloading the blockchain? im developing a software to do a testnet (later it will be in mainnet) transaction with a custom message embedded into OP_RETURN. if the users have to download the whole blockchain, the users im targeting for this software, will not be interested of using this.

Comment: It seems to me that you were just re-asking the same question again, if you disagree with this close-vote please explain the difference between your questions clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are developing in java using the `bitcoinj` library, they have a mechanism in place to do it without downloading the full block chain. They just download the header `lightweight simplified payment verification (SPV) mode`. Maybe you can try that.This is the [link](https://bitcoinj.github.io/)

Comment: Thanks alot jgm. im thinking of developing the software in C#. do C# has a library such like that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regtest instead. You may enable regtest with

```
bitcoind --regtest
```

With console output:

```
bitcoind --regtest --printtoconsole
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the bitcoind, i will be needing the whole blockchain right?

[Do I need the bitcoin blockchain for having a simple wallet using the bitcoind (daemon)?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/19105/do-i-need-the-bitcoin-blockchain-for-having-a-simple-wallet-using-the-bitcoind)